# Git revision with relative indices

Tags: git, version-control, revision

Passing testing on GIT, i cant understand this task:

`Indicate SHA-1 revision identifiers (all 40 characters) with relative indices *.
f42d~2 = *type here*
b197^^ = *type here*
b197ae5^1~2^ = *type here*`

Can someone solve and explain? Pls

P.S. I'm so sorry for my english

Comment: You will find the explanation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_ancestry_references

Comment: And no one could solve because we don't know your git history...

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions